# How to print multiple PDF using angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pdf, angular9

I want to implement print for multiple PDF files in a single click using angular 9.

**For example:** on click, we will take an array of PDF's and then print:

```
printPDF(){
    pages = ["dummy1.pdf", "dummy2.pdf, dummy3.pdf"];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var oWindow = window.open(pages[i], "print");
    print();
    close();
   }
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you fix the syntax here? You're missing a closing bracket (also one of the closing brackets is outside of your code block).

Comment: @Luke Thank you to highlight. it was a typo but still good observation.